# "Baking" spline

Tags: splines

I have downloaded a great model of a chainsaw.
The author of this model seems to have created the "teeth" of the chainsaw with a spline, at least that's what it looks like to me. Here is a screenshot:

[image]
[image]

I would like to use the model and its teeth in a game, so I would need the shape to be "baked", I think.

When I delete this object, the teeth look like a flattened line::
[image]

Could anybody please tell me how to "bake" the spline so that the teeth stay in the bent position even after I exported the chainsaw as an obj or so?

I have uploaded the project here:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45905

Thank you very much.

Comment: Teeth selected, look at the right in the property panel and in the "modifiers" tab. You will see a "curve" modifier. Click the "apply" button on it.

Comment: Alt+C and convert to mesh.

Comment: Both work great, thank you, you two! I don't know if both do exactely the same, but they both did the job. Thank you again!

Comment: @tmighty - using convert to mesh on a mesh object will apply all modifiers, so yes it should give the same result as manually applying them.

Comment: So, as @sambler said, In your case, this is not exactly the same as your object has two modifiers.

Comment: Can  anybody tell me how to animate this in Unity 3D? I guess that extends the scope of the question, but I thought I might ask anyway...